# keep header visible whilst user scrolls down a page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a simple layout. Here is my attempt so far.

```css
#parent{ background: #999;padding:10px;}

.child {background:#ccc;height:200px;margin:20px;}
```

```html
<div id="parent">

    <div class="child">Foo
    </div>
    <div class="child">Bar
    </div>
    <div class="child">Baz
    </div>
        
</div>
```

I want the header to remain so that when the user scrolls down the page the header remains in view. So I added the line below however that makes everything go a bit crazy. How do I achieve the effect of keeping the header visible when a user is scrolling?

```
 position: fixed;
```

Comment: First of all, please include all the relevant code directly inside your question, do not just dump it onto external platforms - [mre]. And second, show what you applied where in there already, and give a _proper_ explanation of what goes wrong (not _“makes everything go a bit crazy”_.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `position: sticky`.

```css
#parent{ background: #999;padding:10px;}

.child {background:#ccc;height:200px;margin:20px;}

.child:first-child {background: red; position: sticky; top: 0;}
```

```html
<div id="parent">

    <div class="child">Foo
    </div>
    <div class="child">Bar
    </div>
    <div class="child">Baz
    </div>
        
</div>
```